# Python split multiples comma

Tags: python, arrays, split

I have a CSV string like this :

```
foo = "value0,value1,value2,value3,value4".split(",")
test(foo)
```

I'm using split to split this string in an array. Then I've a function that takes the array and assign these value to some internal variables :

```
def test(foo):
   var0 = foo[0]
   var1 = foo[1]
   var2 = foo[2]       
   var3 = foo[3]
   var4 = foo[4]
return
```

The problem is that I can have some missing value like this :

```
foo = "value0,value1,,,value4".split(",")
```

Split in these situation creates a smaller array :

```
print(foo) # ['value0','value1','value4']
```

So when I call my function it doesn't work and the value4 is wrongly associated to the var2 ( it should be associated to the var4 ).

Is there a way to force split to create empty element ?  Thanks for any tips.

Comment: *Split in these situation creates a smaller array* Really? I get `['value0', 'value1', '', '', 'value4']` if I split `"value0,value1,,,value4"`, which is what I would expect

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, and I can split them perfectly.

Comment: @LingboTang This works the same way regardless of the version of python. I don't know what the OP is doing

Comment: @NullUserException, I think it is, it will keep the blank anyways.

Comment: It's a really easy regular expression: `/,+/`

Comment: @self That is literally the opposite of the OP wants (from what I understand)

Comment: his question is confusing anyway, voting to close

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove/filter the empty strings after splitting the string, and since you are not aware of the length of your items you can use a dictionary in order to preserve your strings.

```
my_vars = {'var{}'.format(i):j for i, j in enumerate(mystr.split(','))  if j}
```

Here is a Demo:

```
>>> foo = "value0,value1,,,value4"
>>> my_vars = {'var{}'.format(i):j for i, j in enumerate(foo.split(',')) if j}
>>> my_vars
{'var4': 'value4', 'var1': 'value1', 'var0': 'value0'}
```

After that you can simply access your items with a simple indexing:

```
>>> my_vars['var1']
'value1'
```

Comment: "*After that you can simply access your items with a **simple indexing***" As opposed to complex indexing if you just do `foo = mystr.split(',')` and then use `foo[i]`

Comment: @NullUserException We want to access to some items with names! not just integer indices.

Comment: True, but the names seem rather useless if you're just doing `var1`, `var2,` ... `varn`. Might as well use indices

Comment: I think you just made the scenario too complicated, it's unnecessary to filter the empty string.

Comment: @LingboTang We are not filling the empty strings, we are removing them.

Comment: @NullUserException Yes, but the aim is giving the correct approach. Maybe someone comes across the question with different names :-).

Comment: @Kasramvd I fixed the typo, I agreed with your point, but your answer is a little further than the question want to reach.

Comment: @LingboTang *a little further* not only hurts anybody, but also helps/teaches them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `splitlines` with `split`, it working fine on my system
or you can Try this

```
for lines in foo.splitlines():
    print (lines.split(','))
```

will produce this result

```
['value0', 'value1', '', '', 'value4']
```

where foo was `foo = "value0,value1,,,value4"`

although i am using python 3 and `foo.split(',')` is also producing the desired result